# Fetch rows from two mysql tables about geographic areas

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop, geospatial

I have two tables:

zipcodes: id | state | district | zipcode (about 40k records)

county: id | state | district | county (478 records)

Here is the sample data:

[zipcodes table](http://www2.census.gov/geo/relfiles/cdsld13/natl/natl_zccd_delim.txt)

[county table](http://www2.census.gov/geo/relfiles/cdsld13/natl/natl_cocd_delim.txt)

Here is a snapshot of both tables from phpmyadmin:
[image]
Here is what I have tried:

```
select a.state, a.district,a.zipcode,
b.county from zipcodes a inner join
county b on a.state=b.state and
a.district =b.district
```

But it returns a huge number of rows where each zipcode is duplicated 12 times.

state and district rows have same values. What I am trying to do is fetch and echo:

state | district | zipcode | county

by matching state and district rows from both tables since there are multiple zipcodes per county.

I have tried using while loop inside a while loop and that didn't work. I also tried using JOIN when selecting but it was also incorrect.

What would be the best approach to make this happen?

Comment: A `join`.  What does your query look like?  Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I added the sample data. Its basicly census data sorted by zip code and by county with state and district being the common fields. I just want to have them all displayed together.

Comment: My query looks like the answer provided below but that doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure you are provided correct table data in your question?

Comment: I just updated the question with snapshots from phpmyadmin. by the way thanks for following up.

Comment: @user3088202-please provide your expected output for above example data

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.state, a.district,a.zipcode,
b.county from zipcodes a inner join
county b on a.state=b.state and
a.district =b.district
```

Comment: That didn't work. There are only 500 rows the county table and over 40k in zip codes. Right now its shows 12 identical zip codes per row.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not paying close attention to the meanings of your tables and queries.

I'll assume that

- states partition the country
- districts partition a state
- counties partition a state
- zipcodes partition the intersection of a district and a county

The tables hold rows where

```
in state [state] district [district] contains zipcode [zipcode] ...
in state [state] county [county] intersects district [district] ...
```

and when you join the tables you get rows where

```
    in state [state] district [district] contains zipcode [zipcode] ...
AND in state [state] county [county] intersects district [district] ...
```

So when a district and county intersect, that district and county appear with all the district's zipcodes. Ie a zipcode appears with a district and many counties. But that's not what you want! What you (presumably) want is, the zipcodes in the intersection of a district and a county. Ie a zipcode with its district and county. But that information cannot be derived from your tables. You need another table to tell you the county for every zip code. Then you can join the two zipcode tables on zipcode.

```
    in state [state] district [district] contains zipcode [zipcode] ...
AND county [county] contains zipcode [zipcode]
```

The fact is, your tables are probably derived using a table that does have the district and county for every zip code.

The situation may be more complex depending on whether my assumptions are correct. Maybe zipcodes can cross district and/or county boundaries and/or state boundaries.

This is an example of 2-dimensional intervals with canonical-form issues like with temporal databases, where the intervals are 1-dimensional.

**PS** (After writing the above.)

Googling "do district boundaries cross zip codes":

> The Congressional District - ZIP Code Databases for the ...
>   https://www.zipinfo.com/products/cdz/cdz.htm
>   If the 5-digit ZIP code does cross a congressional district boundary,
>   you must use the street address to determine the correct congressional
>   district for any ...

Googling "can a zip code cross state lines":

> ZIP Code FAQ - from carrierroutes.com
>   www.carrierroutes.com/ZIPCodes.html
>   This number can fluctuate by a
>   few thousand ZIP Codes annually, depending on .... ZIP Codes rarely
>   cross state lines, but cross county lines as often as 10%.

This means indeed we need more complex bulleted assumptions replacing the fourth one. At this point I really don't know what query you want. Maybe you want each zip code and its district-county intersections. (If there's more than one per zip code, you need to id intersections. Maybe the COUNTY TABLE already gives exactly those ids of intersections of state, district and county. Although no relationship with zip codes.)

```
zipcode [zipcode] contains the intersection [id] of
    state [state], district [district] and county [county]
```

I don't know what particular tables you can use to build your query from but the basic data is just an artifact of how the state, district, county and zip code boundaries were drawn.

I'll leave you with a full paragraph from the district-zipcode link:

> Other useful data...
>   Using the Congressional District - ZIP Code
>   Database, you can find every ZIP code which lies partially or
>   completely within a given congressional district. Or you can find all
>   congressional districts which contain some portion of a particular ZIP
>   code. You also can find the cities, counties, and county FIPS codes
>   associated with each congressional district. Or you can identify all
>   ZIP codes which lie within a particular congressional district and
>   also lie within a particular MSA/PMSA.